# IOS responsiveness

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a header and footer script here but when I scroll back up on IOS there is the scroll bouncing and it records last scroll as a down scroll and hides my header ( important to be shown at top = 0).

What to do to give that condition to overrides this script?

```js
jQuery.event.special.touchstart = {
  setup: function(_, ns, handle) {
    this.addEventListener('touchstart', handle, {
      passive: !ns.includes('noPreventDefault')
    });
  }
};
jQuery.event.special.touchmove = {
  setup: function(_, ns, handle) {
    this.addEventListener('touchmove', handle, {
      passive: !ns.includes('noPreventDefault')
    });
  }
};
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.querySelector(".header").style.top = "0";
    document.querySelector(".navicon").style.top = "8px";
    document.querySelector(".groupticket").style.top = "6px";
    document.querySelector(".search").style.top = "14px";
    document.querySelector(".foot").style.bottom = "0px";
    document.querySelector(".filter").style.top = "-50px";
  } else {
    document.querySelector(".header").style.top = "-86px";
    document.querySelector(".navicon").style.top = "8px";
    document.querySelector(".groupticket").style.top = "6px";
    document.querySelector(".search").style.top = "14px";
    document.querySelector(".foot").style.bottom = "-201px";
    document.querySelector(".filter").style.top = "0px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

I added this but it seems to mess with the script:

```
var idVar = setTimeout() => { 
  onscroll() 
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Hi and welcome! Just FYI: 1. Tags don't go in titles. 2. Java and JavaScript are **very** different things.

Comment: Add timeout for your `onScroll` event. Now it fires too often

Comment: Ok thanks I'll figure this out!

Comment: 3. jquery is not  (pure) javascript

Comment: "jquery is not (pure) javascript "

Should I use this instead? document.getElementsByClassName('test')

Answer (score 0):

This code uses a function that is listening "scroll" on the page and after 2 seconds executes the command. I did the same script for the footer as well:

```js
var isScrolling;
navbar = document.getElementById("header");
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  header.style.top = "-50px" + header.style.height;
  window.clearTimeout(isScrolling);
  isScrolling = setTimeout(function() {
    header.style.top = "0";
  }, 2000);
}, false);
```